# Need details on increasing google analytics quota limits

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I am a developer and working on a website that uses Google Analytics standard account. I use core-analytics Apis (for .Net) for querying GA to fetch different details such as total page hits, unique page hits, avg. time spent on a page, last viewed date for each web object in the web site.

I need to make 2 queries for each web object to get all these details and we have a large number of such web objects to fetch data for. In past few days I have noticed that these statistics are not being retrieved for some objects. In the logs I found an exception “Quota Error: User Rate Limit Exceeded” which states that I am exceeding the quota limit.

When researched this error, I found that below are some threshold limits that are applicable to GA standard account:

> General quotas:
>
> 50,000 requests per project per day
>
> 10 queries per second (QPS) per IP
>
> Core reporting API quotas:
>
> 10,000 requests per view (profile) per day
>
> 10 concurrent requests per view (profile)

I am not sure if which of these quotas are being exceeded. But I suspect that either 10 QPS or 10,000 req/view is being exceeded.

Question 1 : Could you please let me know if there is any way by which I can increase these quota limits(even if it involves extra cost by switching to premium account).

Question 2 : If we cannot increase the quota, can anyone please guide me how can we fetch details such as total page hits, unique page hits, avg. time spent on a page, last viewed date in a single query instead of two.

Please let me know in case you need any other details from my end.

Answer (score 0):

First off you cant increase either the `10 queries per second (QPS) per IP`  or  `10,000 requests per view (profile) per day`

If you rerun the request and it doesn't work then you may be hitting the `10,000 requests per view (profile) per day` once you hit that its not going to work again for that profile until the next day.

If you are unable to make any requests against any views then you are probably hitting the 50 k limit which you can request an extension of.  It normally takes a month or so to get an extension.

As for the 10 requests a second I suggest you slow down your application and make sure that you aren't running to fast.  You can also add [quota user](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/parameters) which can help with that.